# Is there any template for hyperref forms?

Tags: templates, forms

Hyperref seems excellent for writing a 1-2 page form with single-line and multi-line fields. However, I can't manage to find a LaTeX template that makes a document of hyperref form fields look pretty or even passable. Am I overlooking something? Where can I find a form template?

Comment: Its better to read the documentation of `hyperref.sty` before you proceed

Comment: @MadyYuvi I read the form chapter in the [hyperref docs](https://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/hyperref-doc.pdf) (ch 9), is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same

Comment: There is the eforms packge (acrotex bundle).  It is mostly used for lyperref's interactive featuers.

Comment: @MadyYuvi Alright, I did read it before asking my question. Since you're asking I guess I must have missed something? The reason I'm using LaTeX is to get beautifully typeset documents without having to know typograpy or graphics design, so I figured there would similarly be ready-made solutions for LaTeX forms.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks, I'll check eforms out!

Comment: it is difficult to exactly control the layout of form fields as various aspects like the font size, the baseline, the border can depend on the pdf reader you use. See also the various l3pdffield-XX documentations in the pdfmanagement-testphase bundle.

Comment: Thank you @UlrikeFischer!